# How to stop the sound which has been started by a notification?

Tags: android, notifications

I want to use the TYPE_RINGTONE but if that song is to long, i want to stop it with a button. How i can do that? Thanks.

`NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);`
`builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));`
`builder.setTicker(getString(R.string.notification_text));`
`builder.setContentText(getString(R.string.notification_text));`
`builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_monocromogordo);`
`builder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE));`
`builder.build();`

Comment: If you cancel your notification the sound will be stop.

Comment: So, if i want to don't remove the notification, i need to create another one right after the first one is canceled, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe, but why do you set long notification sound?

Comment: I need a long sound like an alarm, but I don't want an alarm sound, so I have used the ringtone. I've created a notification without the builder.setsound() to replace the first one, but the sound keeps going. So I've created another one with a notification sound which cancels the alarm sound. It's not perfect but for now it's a solution.